# SDL 2.0 compiles, but failt to run

Tags: c++, linux, runtime, shared-libraries, sdl

Im using the latest SDL 2.0 version on Xubuntu 64-bits. I installed through the provided install script on the source code.

Compiling works well, however when trying to open a font or image (regardless of its extension), it will always fail to open.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>


int main (int argc, char *argvp[])
{


    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
    {
        cout << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    }


    if (TTF_Init() == -1)
    {
        std::cout << TTF_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }


    TTF_Font *font1 = NULL;

    font1 = TTF_OpenFont("SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf", 20);  
    if (font1 == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR OPENING FONT = " << TTF_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    TTF_CloseFont(font1);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with

```
g++ -Wall fontTEST.cpp -o TEST -lSDL2 -lSDL_ttf (NOTE that SDL_ttf installs as such, not as SDL2_ttf)
```

And get the following error: `Failed to load font: 0 Couldn't load font file`

This happens with images as well. I've already tried with different fonts and images, apparently it works if I compile with SDL 1.2, just not with 2.0.
Also why does the provided install script installs the lib and include folders in /user/local/?

I moved them to /usr/ but the problem persists.

Comment: Where is "SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf" located?

Comment: in the exact same folder as the source and executable, I already tried with fnts names "asd.ttf". It is not a name error

Comment: Have you tried `strace`? I find it strange that it prints a different message from your message.

Comment: Try changing the path. Maybe it looks for the file where the actual .cpp file is. Does SDL provide a working dir const? If not, try to modify the path you are loading to match the file system structure. I.e: Source code in "app/src/fontTEST.cpp" and asset in "app/bin/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf". If so, try the path: "../bin/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf"

Comment: heres the full output of changing the path

alex@anon:~/Documents/Code/C++/SDL2_Tests$ ./TEST
ERROR OPENING FONT = Couldn't open ~/Documents/Code/C++/SDL2_Tests/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf

Comment: Also here is the strace call for the font:


17:43:33 open("~/Documents/Code/C++/SDL2_Tests/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
17:43:33 fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 8), ...}) = 0
17:43:33 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f730af88000
17:43:33 write(1, "ERROR OPENING FONT = Couldn't op"..., 93ERROR OPENING FONT = Couldn't open ~/Documents/Code/C++/SDL2_Tests/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf

Comment: And the font is really in "~/Documents/Code/C++/SDL2_Tests/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf"?

Comment: Try using a direct path. e.g. /home/user/Documents/Code/C++/SDL2_Tests/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf. Since the problem is not with with SDL, but rather that it fails to open the file. Also check permission of the ttf file. Make sure that your program is allowed to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the following:

- On Unix, file paths are case-sensitive
- As said in Xonar's comment, tilde '~' expansion is a shell feature, it does not work in C/C++ programs, you should use the real path instead.

The strace log says clearly that something is wrong with the path.

You should try the following:

- Rename your font file to "font.ttf"
- put it in /home/user/font.ttf
- use "/home/user/font.ttf" as the path in your code.